# Pointer to structure array shows only the first character of a char field

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I have the following code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Materie {   //grades 
    float romana;
    float matematica;
    float fizica;

};

struct Elev {  // students structure, name, prename and grade obtained;
    char nume[30];
    char prenume[30];
    Materie nota;
};

void absolvent(Elev* elevi, int &n) { // fuction to remove studens with grade < 5
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (elevi[i].nota.fizica < 5.0 || elevi[i].nota.matematica < 5.0 || elevi[i].nota.fizica < 5.0) {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                *elevi[j].nume = *elevi[j + 1].nume;
                *elevi[j].prenume = *elevi[j + 1].nume;
                elevi[j].nota.romana = elevi[j + 1].nota.romana;
                elevi[j].nota.matematica = elevi[j + 1].nota.matematica;
                elevi[j].nota.fizica = elevi[j + 1].nota.fizica;
            }
            n--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int n;
    do {
        cout << "Introduceti numarul de elevi: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 0 || n > 30) {
            cout << "0 < n < 30";
        } 
    } while (n < 0 || n > 30);
    Elev* elevi = new Elev[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Introduceti numele elevului " << i + 1 << " : ";
        cin >> elevi[i].nume;
        cout << "Introduceti prenumele elevului " << i + 1 << " : ";
        cin >> elevi[i].prenume;
        cout << "Introduceti nota obtinuta la limba romana: ";
        cin >> elevi[i].nota.romana;
        cout << "Introduceti nota obtinuta la matematica: ";
        cin >> elevi[i].nota.matematica;
        cout << "Introduceti nota obtinuta la fizica: ";
        cin >> elevi[i].nota.fizica;
    }
    cout << elevi[0].nume << endl;
    cout << *elevi[0].nume << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to implement a function that removes the Elev (student), from the array, if one of the grades he obtained is less than 5.
I want to do it by using array, not vectors.

While doing the exercise, the following questions araised :

1). Why, in the absolvent fuction, the IDE expects me to pass * to elevi[i].nume (i get an error if i input only elevi[i].nume: "expression must be a modifiable lvalue") , but, for the elevi[i].nota.romana it's the opposite (i get an error trying to put *elevi[i].nota.romana: "operand of '*" must pe a pointer") ?

2). Why does the elevi[0].nume, returns "Alex" for example if i input Alex in console, but for *elevi[0].nume returns only A ?

Comment: `*elevi[j].nume = *elevi[j + 1].nume;` -- This is not how you copy C-style char arrays.  Arrays are not copyable using `=`.  Use `strcpy`.

Comment: If you really need to use `char` arrays instead of `std::string` you should learn about `strcpy` and other null-terminated byte string functions

Comment: Also,  `for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {*elevi[j].nume = *elevi[j + 1].nume;` -- If `n` is the number of items, then accessing item `j + 1` will cause an out-of-bounds access on the last iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for `*elevi[j].nume` only showing the first character is that it is the same as `elevi[j].nume[0]`, which is more obvious.

You can't assign to arrays, but you *can* assign to structs and classes that contain arrays, and the solution is much simpler than you were assuming.

```
for (int j = i; j < n-1; j++) {
    elevi[j] = elevi[j+1];
}
```

will do exactly what you want.
(Note that you need to lower the end of the loop, or you will go outside the valid indices.)